# Create a coefficient matrix and augmented matrix for the following

Tags: matrices

A company wants to make $5$ identical flower arrangements. They have $\$610$ to spend for this type of arrangement and want $24$ flowers for each arrangement. Tulips cost $\$4$ each, Lilies cost $\$3$ each and orchid flowers cost $\$6$ each. They want to have twice as many orchid flowers as the other two flowers combined in each arrangement. How many orchid flowers, tulips and lilies are there in each arrangement?

This problem confuses me a lot. A little help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ represent the number of orchids, tulips, and lilies in each arrangement. It remains to translate each constraint into a linear equation.

---

**Constraint 1:**

> "They [...] want $24$ flowers for each arrangement."

---

**Constraint 2:**

> "They have $\$610$ to spend for <s>this type of arrangement</s> **all five identical arrangements in total** and [...] Tulips cost $\$4$ each, Lilies cost $\$3$ each and orchid flowers cost $\$6$ each."

---

**Constraint 3:**

> "They want to have twice as many orchid flowers as the other two flowers combined in each arrangement."